# Write Metadata to S3 Object via Put operation

Tags: kotlin, amazon-s3, metadata, aws-java-sdk

I'm trying to create an empty object with just a metadata in the S3 bucket via Kotlin but it's not working. The object is created but the meta data isn't there. This is the code I'm using:

```
    val metaList = mapOf("x-amz-website-redirect-location" to "https://someurl")
    val metaData = ObjectMetadata()
    metaData.userMetadata = metaList
    s3client.putObject(
        "somebucket",
        "somekey",
        InputStream.nullInputStream(),
        ObjectMetadata()
    )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You create an instance of `ObjectMetadata`

```
val metaData = ObjectMetadata()
metaData.userMetadata = metaList
```

But, then you don't use it. Instead, you create another instance during the call:

```
s3client.putObject(
    "somebucket",
    "somekey",
    InputStream.nullInputStream(),
    ObjectMetadata()
)
```

You should pass in your `metaData` into `s3client.putObject`

```
s3client.putObject(
    "somebucket",
    "somekey",
    InputStream.nullInputStream(),
    metaData
)
```

Comment: Ah...didn't know why I couldn't see it earlier. Thanks!